# swift iOS can't uninstall manually installed alamofire

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I can't install Alamofire form my Xcode project. I installed is **Embedded Framework** I've added it under Embedded Binaries clicking on the + sign.

But now I have removed it from there by clicking on the - sign and also deleted the alamofire.xporj in my project folder but I still get errors in my code related to Alamofire.

I have no reference in my own code to Alamofire either. So how do I remove or delete a embedded framework?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @myles something about "target alamofire..." I can't check right now since I don't have my comp with me. But what is the right way to remove a framework?

Comment: Should be fine the way your are doing it. As long as you remove it from the Navigator area on the left of Xcode, remove it from the Embedded Binaries and possibly also check under Build Phases as well to see nothing is left in any of the sections there it should be gone. You could also do Product > Clean and also try Window > Projects, and then selecting your project on the left and deleting derived data. But from the sounds of things it should be gone. If you're still having issues post the error message, may give more insight.

Comment: @myles thanks! in the navigator area I choose "move to trash" and not remove reference if that matters. But I will double check your steps once I get back on my comp.

Comment: Move to trash is fine. If you remove reference, it removes whatever you are removing from the Xcode project, but the files themselves remain in the directory they are in. Move to trash goes one step further and actually moves the files themselves to trash as well as removing the reference.